# How can I get the users IP and hostname using Java

Tags: java, ip, localhost, remote-host

```
InetAddress addr = java.net.InetAddress.getRemoteHost();
MyHost = addr.getHostName();
IPaddressString = addr.getHostAddress();
```

The above code returns the users local data being 127.0.0.1 and Localhost

Comment: explain a little more what you are trying to do?  do you have an active socket connection and you are attempting to get the IP address of the other end?

Comment: Question is unclear. When you say user do you mean client connecting to you ?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you want the IP of the remote user then you must have his Domain Name , if you want 
       his Domain Name then you must have his IP.

**2.** Now i hope you are in LAN Environment, and have configured the IPs correctly.

**3.** Try assigning your PC with an ip suppose 192.168.20.1 and the other pc as 192.168.20.2

**4.** If you have Domain Name Associated with the remote pc, then you will get his Domain Name in return by using your code.